# oracle apex floating Region that is fixed in place while scrolling screen

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, fixed, floating, region

There are 2 regions on my Oracle apex page, the top one is like a header section, which I want to keep it "floating" on the top the screen while the rest of the page scroll. (like the invoice header info always available when the user scrolls through a long transaction log.)

I have done some google search on this and someone suggested identifying the parent class(e.g. "parent_class") to the Region Header, and add the following CSS to the header of the region

```
.parent_class{
    margin-top:0;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
}
```

I tried but seems like not working unless I got the parent class wrong.

Can someone please give me some advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `top` instead of `margin-top`.

Here is the technique I have used in the past...

http://www.modernapex.co.uk/floatingbuttons/

You wont need the JS stuff I don't think, as that's about switching a region between fixed and static, but the technique may interest you.